# Python 3.4.4 settin argument in Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm using Tkinter lib and i have problem here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *

# ---------------- code for class: curry [BEGIN] ----------------
class curry:
    """from Scott David Daniels'recipe
    "curry -- associating parameters with a function"
    in the "Python Cookbook"
    http://aspn.activestate.com/ASPN/Python/Cookbook/
    """

    def __init__(self, fun, *args, **kwargs):
        self.fun = fun
        self.pending = args[:]
        self.kwargs = kwargs.copy()

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if kwargs and self.kwargs:
            kw = self.kwargs.copy()
            kw.update(kwargs)
        else:
            kw = kwargs or self.kwargs
        return self.fun(*(self.pending + args), **kw)
# ---------------- code for class: curry [END] ------------------

class SampleApp:
    def __init__(self, parent):

        self.textfield = None

        self.myParent = parent
        self.Container = Frame(parent)
        self.Container.pack()

        self.textfield = Entry(self.Container, bg="red")
        self.textfield.pack()

        self.button = Button(self.Container, text="Get", command=curry(self.TestFunction, self.on_button()))
        self.button.pack()

    def on_button(self):
        self.textfield = self.textfield.get()
        #Why isn't print value set in text field
        #print(self.textfield)
        return self.textfield

    def TestFunction(self, var):
        print(var)

root = Tk()
myapp = SampleApp(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Why Test Function() didn't get the returned value from on_button() function? And why didnt print(self.textfield)?

When I didn't use returned value, everything is OK. I mean when I'm just want print value from textfield to console, but when I want use it like argument it is not working.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Can you show with examples?

Comment: just get text from 'textfiled' set it to variable and send to function using curry. It's all, and seems simple ... But i have problem.

Comment: why send to curry? What do you want to do there? Also, you are calling `self.on_button()` when creating the curry object itself, so it would only be called once at the time of creation of the object.

Comment: just looka at http://www.ferg.org/thinking_in_tkinter/all_programs.html and find tt078.py capter. If i didnt use curry or Lambda function being executed, even before the event loop is started, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page you linked here , and the chapter you are talking about - `tt078.py` . Talk about calling a function and passing arguments to it.

In your case that is not the case, in the line -

```
self.button = Button(self.Container, text="Get", command=curry(self.TestFunction, self.on_button()))
```

The function `self.on_button()` would be called when this line is executed and its return value would be passed onto create the `curry` object. Since this line would be reached before you get any chance to add any text to the textbox the `self.on_button()` call return empty string and you would always be printing that.

Also , another issue in your code -

```
    self.textfield = self.textfield.get()
```

This is setting the `self.textfield` to a string, you should not do that, you should instead directly return `self.textfield.get()`.

The easiest way to solve your issue would be to send in the function object for `self.on_button` , without calling it and have `TestFunction()` call it and print the result instead. Example -

```
from tkinter import *

# ---------------- code for class: curry [BEGIN] ----------------
class curry:
    """from Scott David Daniels'recipe
    "curry -- associating parameters with a function"
    in the "Python Cookbook"
    http://aspn.activestate.com/ASPN/Python/Cookbook/
    """

    def __init__(self, fun, *args, **kwargs):
        self.fun = fun
        self.pending = args[:]
        self.kwargs = kwargs.copy()

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if kwargs and self.kwargs:
            kw = self.kwargs.copy()
            kw.update(kwargs)
        else:
            kw = kwargs or self.kwargs
        return self.fun(*(self.pending + args), **kw)
# ---------------- code for class: curry [END] ------------------

class SampleApp:
    def __init__(self, parent):

        self.textfield = None

        self.myParent = parent
        self.Container = Frame(parent)
        self.Container.pack()

        self.textfield = Entry(self.Container, bg="red")
        self.textfield.pack()

        self.button = Button(self.Container, text="Get", command=curry(self.TestFunction, self.on_button))
        self.button.pack()

    def on_button(self):
        return self.textfield.get()

    def TestFunction(self, var):
        print(var())

root = Tk()
myapp = SampleApp(root)
root.mainloop()
```

---

But this is not really needed in your case, you can directly pass in your function object to `command` argument and have that function print the string (or work on it instead). Example -

```
from tkinter import *

class SampleApp:
    def __init__(self, parent):

        self.textfield = None

        self.myParent = parent
        self.Container = Frame(parent)
        self.Container.pack()

        self.textfield = Entry(self.Container, bg="red")
        self.textfield.pack()

        self.button = Button(self.Container, text="Get", command=self.on_button)
        self.button.pack()

    def on_button(self):
        print(self.textfield.get())

root = Tk()
myapp = SampleApp(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: when I'm just want print value from textfield to console everything is OK i wrote that, look at http://www.codesend.com/view/48499a64de50b1c8fc07d87f11863d17/
it's my app code, u can see function SetVoltage, it need 3 arguments, and one of them (integer 5 at the moment) its value from Entry field, how i can set this value to value from Entry.

Comment: Just use the first method I gave, and when you want to use it call that argument as a function to get the data you need. Like I did in first example

Comment: OK thanks, sorry for problem but i have 9 AM so I'm sleepy ^^ I have to drink coffe :)

Comment: ehh i dont get it, just do what u say and dont work...
can u take a look http://www.codesend.com/view/a15cd084dd285c10098ef3c0e89c1763/

Comment: you are not calling the voltage inside the `self.Voltage` function . Call it - `voltage()` .

Comment: Are you mean `Button(self.Container3, command = curry(self.SetVoltage(), self.ReturnHandler(), self.ReturnEntry, 1))` ?

Comment: No , inside your `self.SetVoltage` method - `print(voltage())` .

Comment: Ok i think i get it :P `print(voltage())` yes? :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, now it works fine! You're great, and i need to read something more about call function :P